# Why is TFS not getting connected Error 503 the service is temporarily overloaded

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

While trying to connect to TFS, I am getting error "the service is temporarily overloaded".

Even the IE/ Edge is not able to connect to internet.

Both these issues must be interlinked.

I have tried many things given over web, nothing worked.

When I try to add an account I get HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

Comment: Is this an on-prem installation of TFS, or Visual Studio Team Services? You tagged the question with both.

Comment: Yes this is TFS related. I am getting this error while trying to connect to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message "`Error 503 the service is temporarily overloaded`", seems the Private Memory Limit for the Application Pool is not high enough.

Assuming you are using on-premise TFS, try following below steps to narrow down the issue:

1. Open the IIS Manager on your TFS server.
2. Highlight Application Pools and select your `Microsoft Team
   Foundation Server Application Pool` from the list.
3. Right-click and select Advanced Settings.
4. Scroll down and check if the **Private Memory Limit (KB)** is limited, if it's limited, just try to set the value to "0" (A value 0 means there is no limit)
5. Restart the application pool.
6. Also try to restart the TFS server site.

Then try it again.

Other similar threads for your reference:

- [HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable under simple ASP.NET 4.0 web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105764/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable-under-simple-asp-net-4-0-web-site)
- [TFS 503 Service Unavailable when retrieving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240369/tfs-503-service-unavailable-when-retrieving-files)

[image]